# How do I replace div with textarea when I click button (including content)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I recently work with this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GeJkU/

```
    function divClicked() {
        var divHtml = $(this).html();
        var editableText = $("<textarea />");
        editableText.val(divHtml);
        $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
        editableText.focus();
        // setup the blur event for this new textarea
        editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
    }

    function editableTextBlurred() {
        var html = $(this).val();
        var viewableText = $("<div>");
        viewableText.html(html);
        $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
        // setup the click event for this new div
        viewableText.click(divClicked);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div").click(divClicked);
    });
```

It will replace div tags with textarea when i click the div.
My question is, how can i replace div tags with textarea when i click a button using above javascript?

Any Suggestions?

Comment: $('#yourButtonID').click(function(){});

Comment: Which DIV do you want to replace when you click the button?

Comment: Which button? Why not "contentEditable" attribute?

Comment: Is this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/GeJkU/870/) close to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming, I have understood your question, you can try the below.

**HTML:** Add a `button` like below after every `div`.

```
<div>If no background color is set on the Element, or its background color is set to 'transparent', the default end value will be white.</div>
<button class='btn'>Edit</button>
```

**jQuery:** Modify the code as below.

```
function divClicked() {
    var divHtml = $(this).prev('div').html(); //select's the contents of div immediately previous to the button
    var editableText = $("<textarea />");
    editableText.val(divHtml);
    $(this).prev('div').replaceWith(editableText); //replaces the required div with textarea
    editableText.focus();
    // setup the blur event for this new textarea
    editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
}

function editableTextBlurred() {
    var html = $(this).val();
    var viewableText = $("<div>");
    viewableText.html(html);
    $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
    // setup the click event for this new div
    viewableText.click(divClicked);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn").click(divClicked); //calls the function on button click
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/GeJkU/874/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope it helps you,

```
function divClicked(ele) {
    var divHtml = $(ele).parent().find('p').html();
    var editableText = $("<textarea />");
    editableText.val(divHtml);
    $(ele).parent().find('p').replaceWith(editableText);
    editableText.focus();
    // setup the blur event for this new textarea
    editableText.blur(function() {
        editableTextBlurred(this);
    });
}

function editableTextBlurred(ele) {
    $(ele).replaceWith($('<p>').html($(ele).val()));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".update").click(function() {
        divClicked(this);
    });
});
```

please check the demo version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GeJkU/875/).

Answer (score 1):

You can just try something like this:

```js
function div2text(){ 
    $("#div").replaceWith('<textarea>' + $("#div").html() + '</textarea>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  onclick="div2text();" id="div" style="margin: 10px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;"><b>I am a div!</b> <u>Click Anywhere On Me!</u></div><br>
<button id="change" onclick="div2text();">Div-2-Textarea</button>
```

#### References

To learn more about the `.replaceWith` method, visit:

> https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_replacewith.asp

Answer (score 0):

why not place textarea element inside div

```
$("#button_id").click(function(){ 
    $("#div_id").html('<textarea></textarea>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").click(function(){
        divClicked($(this));
    });
});
```

Then change your divClicked function slightly to accommodate the jquery object being passed in:

```
function divClicked(theObject) {
    var divHtml = theObject.html();
    var editableText = $("<textarea />");
    editableText.val(divHtml);
    theObject.replaceWith(editableText);
    editableText.focus();
    // setup the blur event for this new textarea
    editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[see demo....](http://jsfiddle.net/GeJkU/872/)**

**html**

```
<div>If no background color is set on the Element, or its background color is set to 'transparent', the default end value will be white.</div>
<div>Element shortcut method for tweening the background color. Immediately transitions an Element's background color to a specified highlight color then back to its set background color.</div>
<div>Element shortcut method which immediately transitions any single CSS property of an Element from one value to another.</div>

<button id="buttonclick">click</button>
```

**js**

```
function divClicked() {
    var divHtml = [];
    $("div").each(function(){
    divHtml.push($(this).html());
     var editableText = $("<textarea />");
    editableText.val($(this).html());
    $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
     editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
    });
    editableText.focus();
    // setup the blur event for this new textarea

}

function editableTextBlurred() {
    var html = $(this).val();
    var viewableText = $("<div>");
    viewableText.html(html);
    $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
    // setup the click event for this new div
    viewableText.click(divClicked);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonclick").click(divClicked);
});
```

**css**

```
div {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a button like

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" id="btn1" />
```

Then use the following code in your document ready function

```
   $('#btn1').click(function () {
        divClicked.call($('div#one'));
    });
```

Note: I have assigned id `one` to first div.

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ENE9S/)